# Cummulative up vs down volume in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to calculate the cumulative up vs down volume in pinescript for an equity security over a trading day. To do this I am using 1 minute volume data (regardless of the charts timeframe) by defining it as a distinct security, however I am getting values that do not correspond with the total volume for the day.

The chart volume shapes look broadly correct, but the data is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Code as follows:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Ambienz
//@version=5
indicator("Up Down Volume", "Up Down Volume", format = format.volume)

var int   tickDirection         = na
var float volumeUp              = 0
var float cumVolumeUp           = 0
var float volumeDown            = 0
var float cumVolumeDown         = 0
var float prevTickVolume        = 0
var float prevTickClose         = 0
var float volumeRatio           = 0
var float cumNetVolume          = 0

// Reset counters if new day
isNewDay = time("D") != time("D")[1]
if isNewDay 
    volumeUp                    := 0
    cumVolumeUp                 := 0
    volumeDown                  := 0
    cumVolumeDown               := 0  
    prevTickVolume              := 0
    prevTickClose               := 0
    volumeRatio                 := 0
    cumNetVolume                := 0

// Define 1 minute data, regardless of chart timeframe
minuteVolume = request.security( syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = "1", expression = volume)
minuteOpen = request.security( syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = "1", expression = open)
minuteClose = request.security( syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = "1", expression = close)

// Separate up and down volume
tickDirection   := minuteClose > minuteOpen ? 1 : minuteClose < minuteOpen ? -1 : 0 
if tickDirection == 1 //uptick
    volumeUp := minuteVolume
    cumVolumeUp := cumVolumeUp + volumeUp

else if tickDirection == -1 //downtick
    volumeDown := minuteVolume
    cumVolumeDown := cumVolumeDown + volumeDown
    
volumeRatio := cumVolumeUp / cumVolumeDown
cumNetVolume := cumVolumeUp - cumVolumeDown
cumNetVolumeColor = cumNetVolume > 0 ? color.rgb(57, 250, 74) : color.rgb(252, 0, 0)

plot(cumVolumeUp, 'Cumulative Up Volume', style=plot.style_columns, color = color.blue)
plot((-1) * cumVolumeDown, 'Cumulative Down Volume', style=plot.style_columns, color = color.purple)
plot(cumNetVolume, 'Cumulative Net Volume', style=plot.style_line, color = cumNetVolumeColor, linewidth = 3)


dailyVolume = request.security( syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = "D", expression = volume)


var CurrVol = table.new(position = position.bottom_left, columns = 8, rows = 11, bgcolor = color.rgb(0, 0, 0), border_width = 3, border_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = CurrVol,column = 0, row = 0, text_color = color.rgb(57, 250, 74), text_size = size.normal, text = 'Cum. Up Volume:  '+ str.tostring(cumVolumeUp, format.volume), width = 14)
table.cell(table_id = CurrVol,column = 1, row = 0, text_color = color.rgb(57, 250, 74), text_size = size.normal, text = 'Cum. Down Volume:  '   + str.tostring(cumVolumeDown, format.volume), width = 14)
table.cell(table_id = CurrVol,column = 2, row = 0, text_color = color.rgb(57, 250, 74), text_size = size.normal, text = 'Up/Down Ratio:  '+ str.tostring(volumeRatio,format = "#.##") , width = 14)
table.cell(table_id = CurrVol,column = 3, row = 0, text_color = color.rgb(57, 250, 74), text_size = size.normal, text = 'Current Bar Volume:  '+ str.tostring(volume, format.volume) , width = 14)
table.cell(table_id = CurrVol,column = 4, row = 0, text_color = color.rgb(57, 250, 74), text_size = size.normal, text = 'Daily Volume:  '+ str.tostring(dailyVolume, format.volume), width = 14)
```

Produces the following chart:

[image]